# CouchCMS Meta tags added from blog content

Tags: content-management-system, meta, couch-cms

I need a way of adding the article content from the blog as also the meta description of the page. I have tried :

```
<meta name="description" content="<cms:excerptHTML count='40' ignore='img'><cms:show blog_content /></cms:excerptHTML>" />
```

...but what this will do is simply place the blog content above my website and not as the meta description...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be placing the `<meta>` tag in the `<body>` of the page, rather than in the `<head>`. Additionally, I recommend that you use the [excerpt](http://www.couchcms.com/docs/tags-reference/excerpt.html) tag rather than [excerptHTML](http://www.couchcms.com/docs/tags-reference/excerpthtml.html). This will remove `<p>` and other tags, which you don't really want in your meta description. In this case, you won't need to include `ignore='img'` in your code.

If you place the following between the `<head></head>` tags in your page, it should work:

```
<meta name="description" content="<cms:excerpt count='40'><cms:show blog_content /></cms:excerpt>" />
```

Comment: Hah, no, I didn't place the meta tags in the <body> :) They are in the <head> where they should :) you may be right about one thing though, I think removing the HTML from the excerpt did fix my problem back then, I'll check and get back to you :)